# How do you open ax.25 ports?

Tags: digital-modes, software, packet, ax.25

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8OBF47UkeI&t=11s) I almost got to the end, about 9:15 was where I got stuck. Right about there, the speaker is about to wrap up- but I get a couple error messages.

```
2020/8/10 22:22:33 HTTP service (0.0.0.0:5000) 2020/08/10 22/22/33 Listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000 bind address already in use.
```

FYI, I am using a different commputer from the pi, so I will not be able to send over images. Basically though, What I am trying to do is connect the ax.25 so that I can set up Winlink on two meters. There's on option to connect, and then you click on AX.25, followed by my call sign. That's where I get my second error message.

```
connection refused
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? By the way, originally the message was somewhat different. I don't remember the exact details, but I remember the words "data port". Thank you so much, if there's anything I can do to help you solve this mystery, please let me know.

Comment: Due to the actual situation here, a question like this may get better answers on e.g. the SuperUser site? But otoh at least from the asker's perspective it *is* directly about ham-related software and I think other hams and radio aficionados could find it useful so it's a +1 from me.

Comment: Since this is a computer-related technical support question, though, it would be helpful if you could add more details about that, especially what operating system you are using but also a summary of what you've done so we don't have to figure it out from the video itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000 bind address already in use.

This sounds like a somewhat generic error, not necessarily related to your AX.25 software itself but certainly a bummer to encounter it while setting up!

What this means is the software you're trying to run wants to listen on port 5000, on all network interfaces (the `0.0.0.0` part). But something is already listening on that port. Are you already running the same program in a different window?

Depending on your operating system, you may find the following Q&A's helpful:

- Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows
- macOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x
- Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/determining-what-process-is-bound-to-a-port

> connection refused

Without watching the video, this one's a little harder to guess at because you don't say what you were trying to do/run when you got this message. If you're curious in general, you might find the answers at https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message interesting but it's possible that once you fix the first error, then this one might go away on its own.

Comment: thank you. I still don't have my question resolved, but I may make a follow up question. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of a lot reputation on this site, but I may still sacrifice some.